# Flutter ML Kit Pose detection do not match with screen positions

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter ML Kit Pose detector and followed [Vision  Pose Detector sample](https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/blob/master/example/lib/VisionDetectorViews/pose_detector_view.dart) . When I run it, I can see the positions in the real the camera view. I want to set my own Widget for a given position(right shoulder for example). I was able to get a x cordinator as following:

```
xpos = pose.landmarks[PoseLandmarkType.rightShoulder]!.x;
```

But when a set a Positioned widget to this above x coordinator (xpos), the widget is not located correctly. Even I move the camera, the widget is moving here and there.

setState(() {
x=  xpos ;
y=ypos ;
});

I use a stack and change its left and top with above x and y. (for now, only x coordinate is considered.)

Can anyone help me to set the exact position to widget ?
(I found some online docs saying about scaling factor. I tried it, and no luck)

Comment: Please remove the `google-mlkit` tag, since the Flutter plugin you use is neither owned, nor endorsed by the Google ML Kit team.  If you think it's related to the Flutter plugin, please use their issue reporting site (https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues) to contact them.